# Web push notification badge reverts to bell after a while

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, web-push, chrome-for-android

In a web push notification, it is possible to specify a "[badge](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification)" to customize the appearance of the logo in the notification which otherwise defaults to a bell (in Chrome for Android, anyway).

[image: Default badge in Chrome for Android web push notifications]

I find that this generally works completely fine (in a PWA "added to home screen" through Chrome 81.0.4044.117 on Android 10), but after a while (in my case, after a few weeks at one notification per day), the badge will revert itself to the alarm bell, even though the customized badge is still available.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior? Is this just a bug in Chrome?